# While loops in C

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I tried changing the do-while loop inside this piece of code into a while loop. I compiled my code and ran it but I didn't get any error messages, but my code did not print anything either, so I'm assuming something is wrong with my while loop code. Could someone show me what I did wrong with my while loop code?

```
...
while(fgets(transinput,sizeof(transinput),in)!=NULL){
    i=0;

    do {
            for(j=0;j<npos;j++){
                transchar = transinput[i];
                if(transchar != '\n' && transchar != '\0'){
                    transtemp[j] = transchar;
                    ++i;
                } else {
                    transtemp[j] = ' ';
                }
            }
            for(ii=0;ii<npos;ii++){
                fprintf(out,"%c", transtemp[decrypt[ii]]);
            }
    }
    while(transchar != '\n' && transchar != '\0');

    fprintf(out,"\n");
}
...
```

UPDATED CURRENT CODE:

```
...
i=0;
while(fgets(input3,sizeof(input3),file1)!=NULL){
ch = input3[i];

while(ch != '\0' && ch!='\n'){
    for(j=0;j<npos;j++){
        //ch = input3[i];
        if(ch != '\0' && ch!='\n'){
            temp[j] = ch;
            ++i;
        } else {
            temp[j] = ' ';
        }

     }
     for(k=0;k<npos;k++){
         fprintf(file2,"%c", temp[transposition[k]]);
     }
}

fprintf(file2,"\n");

}
...
```

Comment: `do...while` will always execute at least once, `while` will execute zero or more times.

Comment: Your `while(transchar != '\0' && transchar!='\n'){` loop is invariant: traschar never changes inside the loop. (hint: use for loops instead, and you'll see)

Comment: updated current code, now im running into the problem of only being able to scan in 1 line

Comment: `while(ch != '\0' && ch!='\n')` you meant to do `if(ch != '\0' && ch!='\n')`?

Comment: @user3555494 -- you should not update your code in the question as that invalidate the answer/comments given, and makes it very confusing for people to read -- instead add a section with an update, but leave the initial posting intact.

Comment: Do you know it is USELESS to try to edit to erase your code? I just have to see your edit to see it... And also, please click on the green mark when the answer is the one that fixed your code...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `i=0` got lost going from the `do while` to the `while` implementation.

Even if `i` is initialized to 0 prior to the `while` loop, it is not reset after the first iteration which is a bug.

There is also an issue with `j`.  You set `j` to 0 right after you use it in a `for` loop.

```
for(j=0;j<npos;j++){
    j=0;
```

If `npos` is less than or equal to zero, you won't enter the loop.  If `npos` is greater than zero, you will never leave the loop.

Comment: whoops sorry for that typo

Comment: I am a bit lost then, how should i try to fix my while loop code so that it functions like my do while loop?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will suffice?

```
while(fgets(transinput,sizeof(transinput),in))
   {
   i=0;
   transchar = ' ';

   while(transchar && transchar != '\n')
      {
      for(j=0; j<npos; j++)
         {
         transchar = transinput[i];
         switch(transinput[i])
            {
            case '\0':
            case '\n':
               transchar = transinput[i];
               transtemp[j] = ' ';
               break;

            default:
               transtemp[j] = transinput[i++];
               break;
            }
         }

      for(ii=0; ii<npos; ii++)
         fprintf(out,"%c", transtemp[decrypt[ii]]);
      }

   fprintf(out,"\n");
   }
...
```